Orientation Constraint for KinematicTrajectoryOptimization in Drake
I am following the motion planning with KinematicTrajectoryOptimization tutorial here (with some modifications for the robot I am working with): https://deepnote.com/workspace/pivot-cb0b-55329454-fc88-4d61-90bb-a5f80da3296d/project/06-Motion-Planning-Duplicate-23e10a17-f018-4b89-b8c3-9941f1afca86/notebook/kinematic_trajectory_optimization-12262a07cd75476fb63c9714f1c196ff
I would like to add an orientation constraint to the start and goal poses.
Here's my current code:
start_rotation_constraint = OrientationConstraint(
    plant,
    plant.world_frame(),
    RotationMatrix(),
    gripper_frame,
    start_transform.rotation(),
    0.001,
    plant_context,
)
trajopt.AddPathPositionConstraint(start_rotation_constaint, 0)
goal_rotation_constraint = OrientationConstraint(
    plant,
    plant.world_frame(),
    RotationMatrix(),
    gripper_frame,
    goal_transform.rotation(),
    0.001,
    plant_context,
)
trajopt.AddPathPositionConstraint(goal_rotation_constraint, 1)

I'm not sure if calling AddPathPositionConstraint is the correct function to call here. However, KinematicTrajectoryOptimizer doesn't have a AddPathOrientationConstraint function. (InverseKinematics has AddOrientationConstraint, and I was hoping the KinematicTrajectoryOptimizer would having something similar). Is using AddPathPositionConstraint for orientation ok? It seems to mess up my solver as my solver can no longer find solutions with the collision constraints enabled.
If AddPathPositionConstraint is not the correct function to use, what alternative do I have here?

AddPathPositionConstraint is the right function to call here. You can construct an orientation constraint, and then pass this orientation constraint to AddPathPositionConstraint. Your code above is correct.

Hm, the solver is failing to find a solution once I add the orientation constraint (even with collision constraints turned off). Can I just add constraints on the joint positions instead of the world position of the gripper frame? I.e., place start and end constraints on q?

Yes, you can definitely add constraints directly to q.  For instance you can use AddPathPositionConstraint(lb=q0, ub=q0, s=0) and AddPathPositionConstraint(lb=qf, ub=qf, s=1).
If you do want to use the OrientationConstraint, I would recommend trying a looser tolerance (set the threshold to 0.1 instead of 0.001).

Got it, thanks. Adding path position constraints in terms of q worked for me. The solver was not able to solve the trajectory in terms of world position and orientation constraints, but if I do the IK to get the joint positions and pass that into the solver as a constraint, it works!
